# div height prob after jquery hide()

Tags: jquery, css, height, hide

after hiding some inner divs with jquery hide() function, the outer div height doesn't fit and its height is as long as it was before hiding.

i've this problem with IE, FF not with Chrome.

what's the solution !!
( i can give the page url if requested )

Comment: A minimal example on jsfiddle.net would be excellent.

Comment: @Douglas  would u check it here ? ( right sidebar click (+) sign to expand ) [click here](http://softkharid.com)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the outer div's height did or didn't change?   Remeber when you do a hide() your setting the css to a "display:none".  This means the element will not take up anyspace in the DOM and if it was controlling the height of the outer div, then you will have to manually set the outer div height after it is hidden.

Another option would to be is to let the outer div control the height and then just hide() or show() its contents. that way it will maintain its dimensions.

Hope this helps

Comment: would u explain more ur second suggestion ;)